# Ksh script decode base64 using Perl one-liner

Tags: perl, ksh

Trying to decode `"ZW5jb2RlIG1lCg=="` using this script like `./decodetest.sh '"ZW5jb2RlIG1lCg=="'` doesn't return anything. I'm passing base64 string with single quotes to keep the double quotes for the command. Any help is appreciated or any alternatives.

```
#!/bin/ksh 
OBJECT=$1
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print decode_base64(${OBJECT})'
#echo ${OBJECT}
```

Running below on the command line correctly outputs "encode me".

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print decode_base64("ZW5jb2RlIG1lCg==")'
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than try to make nested quotes work, it would be cleaner to pass the argument through as an argument:

```
#!/bin/ksh
OBJECT=$1
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print decode_base64($ARGV[0])' "$OBJECT"
```

Comment: Even better. I don't have to worry about quoting the input at all. Thanks!

Comment: Or just pass `$1` directly instead of assigning to `OBJECT` and then passing the copy. Although if this was a long code, it makes sense to assign to another variable to make it self documenting.

Answer (score 2):

Shell environment variables are accessible in Perl through the [`%ENV` hash](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#ENV)

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print decode_base64($ENV{OBJECT})'
```

You may need to call `export` on the variable in ksh for it to be visible to subshells.

```
OBJECT=$1
export OBJECT
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print decode_base64($ENV{OBJECT})'
```

or

```
export OBJECT=$1
perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print decode_base64($ENV{OBJECT})'
```